# Continuation of ID counting after sensor reboot

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dataset from sensors with ObjectIDs and Timestamps.

```
id      id   x   y   height  datetime
21124   494 243 243 4524    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21125   438 345 189 1016    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21126   309 314 168 1050    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21127   502 488 229 2535    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21128   503 228 159 831     2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21129   506 234 272 4056    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21130   507 515 284 2477    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21131   508 471 107 1115    2019-09-11 11:53:58.958
21132   2   558 95  1050    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21133   3   379 100 1323    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21134   6   222 240 4860    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21135   2   430 277 2008    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21136   5   246 251 3987    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21137   6   378 114 1303    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21138   4   322 271 3133    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21139   3   339 123 1626    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21140   4   356 159 979     2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
21141   5   465 152 1440    2019-09-11 12:06:43.340
```

Sometimes, the sensor reboots it self and starts to count the object IDs from scratch again. (see the time gap at 11:53/12:06). The problem: After reboot, and if the ID already occured before in the dataset, continue with the counting from the last ID.

So instead of starting over with "2" after the reboot, it should replace the IDs with IDs that continue the counting of the last ID before the reboot, here "508".

ID 2, 3, 6 and so have occured earlier in the dataset, so they need to be replaced. Does this make sense?

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: so, if I get it right, you request the max of id#2 (in your case 508) to continue as 509 etc?

Comment: Yes, you got it. After the reboot should be new, distinct IDs, but starting from the id.max before the reboot.

Comment: I still don't understand the question, but I'd suggest renaming one of your "id" columns (of which you have 2) so it's more clear what you're referring to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**step 1:**
identify your 'good' id by getting the index of `max(id)`

```
max_id = max(df['id'])
max_loc = df.loc[df['id']==max_id]['id'].index[0]
```

hence:

```
ok_ids = list(df[df.index<=max_loc]['id'])
```

**step 2:** get new_ids numerated form the max_id forth.

```
import numpy as np
new_ids = np.arange(1+max_id,max_id+len(df[df.index>max_loc])+1,1)
```

**step 3:** extend and replace the id column:

```
ok_ids.extend(new_ids)
df['id']=ok_ids
```

desired result:

```
         id id.1    x   y   height  datetime
21124   494 243   243   4524    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21125   438 345   189   1016    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21126   309 314   168   1050    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21127   502 488   229   2535    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21128   503 228   159   831 2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21129   506 234   272   4056    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21130   507 515   284   2477    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21131   508 471   107   1115    2019-09-11  11:53:58.958
21132   509 558   95    1050    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21133   510 379   100   1323    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21134   511 222   240   4860    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21135   512 430   277   2008    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21136   513 246   251   3987    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21137   514 378   114   1303    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21138   515 322   271   3133    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21139   516 339   123   1626    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21140   517 356   159   979 2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
21141   518 465   152   1440    2019-09-11  12:06:43.340
```

Note: don't try to change the df['id'] as it will warn you on [returning a view versus a copy (SettingWithCopyWarnning)](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)